# how to increase memory heap in nest.js application ? how to use --max-old-space-size in cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, npm-scripts

I am working on node.js project with nest.js framework and I had the error "JavaScript heap out of memory" 
my question is how to allocate more memory to my app?. Also I found some people say that I should use 
[--max-old-space-size] to allocate memory so I tried to add this option to package.json scripts to have **"start" : "nest start --max-old-space-size=4096"**   but it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Nest passes some, but not all, flags through to `node`. This is one of the flags that it does not. Instead, you can use `node dist/main --max-old-space-size=4096` and get the server to start that way.

Answer (score 4):

[Jay McDoniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel) was right about this, however the argument is in the wrong order, you must pass like this `node --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/main`

Make sure you do a `npm run build` if you haven't before.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I didnt understand your answer, I usually run npm run dev to start my application locally, where should I tun this command you mencioned?