# Increasing heap memory of NestJs application

Tags: node.js, nestjs, heap-memory

I am trying to increase memory heap in my Nestjs application. I've tried updataing my start script to "node dist/main --max-old-space-size=16384" as per [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737242/how-to-increase-memory-heap-in-nest-js-application-how-to-use-max-old-space). However when i test my heapTotal, it isn't changing.
Am i doing something wrong?

I've tried testing memoryUsage() (from node:process) in my application as well as directly from the v8 engine from my terminal.
The values before running my application (with --max-old-space-size=16384) and after remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

The "--max-old-space-size" flag is used to set the maximum heap size for the Node.js process. However, it does not directly affect the heapTotal value reported by the Node.js runtime.

The heapTotal value represents the current size of the heap in bytes, which can dynamically increase or decrease based on the memory requirements of your application

If you're observing that the heapTotal value remains unchanged after increasing the maximum heap size, it could be because your application is not utilizing the additional memory yet.

Observe the heapTotal value over time to see if it increases as your application requires more memory. The heapTotal value may fluctuate as the garbage collector performs its memory management tasks

Node.js runtime and garbage collector are designed to optimize memory usage and automatically manage the heap size based on the application's needs. It's normal for the heapTotal value to vary during runtime, even if you've set a maximum heap size.

Comment: heapTotal value is not something you can directly increase or set manually. It represents the total amount of heap memory currently used by your Node.js application.

The heap memory in Node.js is managed by the V8 engine, which includes a garbage collector responsible for allocating and releasing memory. The garbage collector dynamically adjusts the heap size based on the needs of your application.

Comment: How can I check wether or not updating the "--max-old-space-size" worked?

Comment: Start your Nest.js application using the modified script that includes the --max-old-space-size 

"scripts": {
  "start": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 main.js"
}
This will start your application with a maximum heap size of 2GB (2048 megabytes).

Operating System Monitoring: Use your operating system's monitoring tools to check the memory usage of the Node.js process. Tools like Task Manager (Windows), Activity Monitor (macOS), or top command (Linux) can display the memory consumption of the running process.

Comment: Node.js process.memoryUsage(): You can use the built-in process.memoryUsage() function in your code to get information about the memory usage of your Node.js process. This function returns an object with various memory-related properties, including heapTotal and heapUsed.

const memoryUsage = process.memoryUsage();
console.log('Memory Usage:', memoryUsage);